# How to pass a variable from AccessFilter to Controller in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have an AccessFilter Class

```
class ProjectAccessControl extends \yii\base\ActionFilter
{
   public $a;
   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public function beforeAction($action)
   {
        switch ($action->id) {
          case 'view':
             // code here
             break;
        }
   }
```

In controller I revoke this AccessFilter in behaviour() method like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => ProjectAccessControl::className(),
        ]
    ];
}
```

Now I want to pass the `$a` variable from AccessFilter to an any action in Controller. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply add a variable in your controller, e.g. :

```
public $a;
```

And use this in your filter :

```
$this->owner->a = $this->a;
```